# Derived sets from a base set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, notation

Let's say we have a set $B$. Some of its elements can have two *versions*, let's say $b^+$ and $b^-$, while the rest can only have one: $b^+$.

Now I want to build a set that contains the two versions of those elements that can have them, and the only one version for those elements which have only one.

So my question is: How do I build "derived" sets ? Which formalizes:

- $X$: The set of "$^+$" versions of all elements of $B$
- $Y$: The set of "$^-$" versions of the elements of $B$ which can have them (assume there is a predicate that can be used to detect them)
- Implies $X\cup Y \neq B$

Example:

$B$ can be a set of cars, some of which come in 4wd or 2wd versions, and some only come in 2wd. I'd like to build the set of all possible car versions.

Comment: This means that we have **three** versions: the sedan 4WD, the sedan 2WD and the station wagon (2WD only).

Comment: I think you just want to use ordered pairs. Take the cartesian product of the set of models and the set of options.

Comment: @saulspatz Let's say we call the resulting set $Z$ Can I write $Z  = \lbrace (b,d) | \Phi(b), b\in B \;\text{and} \;d \in \lbrace +,- \rbrace \rbrace \subseteq B \times \lbrace +,-\rbrace$ where $\Phi$ would be my "filtering" predicate ?

Comment: There wouldn't be a predicate there.  What you've written is the Cartesian product.  Then you could write something like $X=\{(x,y)\in Z \mid y = +\}$

Comment: hmm.. watch out, I made an edit to the comment. I guess the question is now, can you define ordered pairs using set builder notation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual ordered pair (x,y) = {{x}, {x,y}}.
Your question is not about sets; it is about multisets or bags.
A simulation of a bag for your problem is
T×{0,1} $\cup$ S×{0},
where T is the set of two version elements
and S is the set of one version elements.

Comment: Actually, I like the pair way to present this. Why is multiset needed if $T \times \lbrace 0,1\rbrace \cup S\times \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ does not have duplicate elements ?

Comment: Also, I still have doubts about the ordered vs unordered pair. Why isn't an unordered pair enough to formalize this kind of structure?

Comment: Clarify what a version is.  Are not the versions the same element?  In set theory, elements do not have versions.  Thus your notions are outside of set theory.